# How to pass value from one resource to another resource in chef recipe?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, recipe

I am trying to change an attribute in one resource and want to use updated value in another resource but updated value is not getting reflected in another resources. please help me

**Code**

```rb
node[:oracle][:asm][:disks].each_key do |disk|
    Chef::Log.info("I am in #{cookbook_name}::#{recipe_name} and current disk count #{node[:oracle][:asm][:test]}") 

    bash "beforeTest" do
        code <<-EOH
            echo #{node[:oracle][:asm][:test]}
        EOH
    end
    ruby_block "test current disk count" do
        block do
            node.set[:oracle][:asm][:test] = "#{node[:oracle][:asm][:test]}".to_i+1
        end
    end
    bash "test" do
        code <<-EOH
            echo #{node[:oracle][:asm][:test]}
        EOH
    end
end
```

The value I'm trying to update is the one stored at `node[:oracle][:asm][:test]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that the `code` variable is set during the compile phase of chef, before the ruby block has changed the value of your attribute.  You need to add a lazy initializer around your code block.

```
Chef::Log.info("I am in #{cookbook_name}::#{recipe_name} and current disk count #{node[:oracle][:asm][:test]}") 

bash "beforeTest" do
  code lazy{ "echo #{node[:oracle][:asm][:test]}" }
end

ruby_block "test current disk count" do
  block do
    node.set[:oracle][:asm][:test] = "#{node[:oracle][:asm][:test]}".to_i+1
  end
end

bash "test" do
  code lazy{ "echo #{node[:oracle][:asm][:test]}" }
end
```

The first block doesn't really need the lazy, but I threw it in there just in case the value is changing elsewhere too.

Comment: Still i am getting error as below:

NoMethodError
-------------
undefined method `echo' for Chef::Resource::Bash


Cookbook Trace:
---------------
/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/Oracle11G/recipes/testSplit.rb:3:in `block (2 levels) in from_file'


Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/Oracle11G/recipes/testSplit.rb

  1: bash "beforeTest" do
  2:   code lazy{
  3:    echo "#{node[:oracle][:asm][:test]}"
  4:   }
  5: end

Comment: sorry, that's just because the command isn't in quotes.  I'll fix it.

Comment: Why would you want to use lazy in a ruby_block?

Comment: @TejayCardon i am blown away. Been using Chef for 3 - 4 years and have tried some pretty elaborate ways to get output from 1 resource into another (especially around encrypted data bags). This solves so many problems. Thanks!!

Comment: @Brett no problem.  The Lazy concept was a HUGE addition to Chef that really did make many more things possible.  Now if only I could use Lazy outside the scope of a recipe....

Answer (score 2):

Lazy is good, but here is another approach.
You may use `node.run_state` for your purposes.

Here is usage example from https://docs.chef.io/recipes.html

```
package 'httpd' do
  action :install
end

ruby_block 'randomly_choose_language' do
  block do
    if Random.rand > 0.5
      node.run_state['scripting_language'] = 'php'
    else
      node.run_state['scripting_language'] = 'perl'
    end
  end
end

package 'scripting_language' do
  package_name lazy { node.run_state['scripting_language'] }
  action :install
end
```